# Does JSONata work in internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jsonata

I'm doing a web project with javascript for the frontend and I'm using JSONata to parse the incoming JSON object that the server returns. It works perfectly well on all the browsers but it's not recognizing JSONata in Internet Explorer.

It just says in the console: 'jsonata' is undefined.

Does JSONata work in Internet Explorer? Or what do I need to do to have JSONata work in Internet Explorer?

Comment: add the code where you are getting this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSONata is written using ES6 features (e.g. generators). I suspect IE11 can't deal with this. Have you tried using the babel transpiled version `jsonata-es5.js`?  This gets built using `npm t`.